Can you make all the squares the same color?
The unit squares of a 9x9 square grid are colored using two colors. It is allowed to choose any 1x3 or 3x1 rectangle (3 consecutive unit squares) and color all its squares with the color that there had been the most of in this rectangle before.
Is it true no matter how the 81 unit squares are colored that using these operations one can reach the situation where all the unit squares are the same color?
Attribution:  Mathematical Circles (Russian Experience)

I claim the answer is

 yes

and here's why:

 Consider the top-left 3×3. You can get it all to the same color by first selecting all the rows, and then selecting all the columns.



 Now, you can expand this single-color rectangle as much as you like: any cells of the opposite color can be "absorbed" into it by simply choosing a cage that has two cells in the rectangle and one cell out of it.



 So you can just expand this rectangle all the way to the right, and all the way down, and you're done.


+1 This is a good answer but it could be even better if you explained why your procedure to make the top-left 3x3 all one color always works.

Well, isn't it fairly obvious? After selecting all the rows, all the rows will be the same color by definition. This means all the columns are identical, so selecting all of them turns them all the same color ... I think the diagram illustrates this pretty clearly

@DanDan面 People here at Puzzling Stack Exchange have different skill levels and experience.  Things that are obvious to some are not necessarily obvious to all.

off topic, but what tool did you use to draw your images?

@justhalf I used penpa! It's meant for formatting logic puzzles - the rectangles I used were the 'cages' meant for Killer Sudoku - but I've found it to be a generally good tool for making diagrams.

ahh, that's why it feels familiar, lol, forgot we can have empty grid in penpa
